# Is setting clock divider worth changing on delay() to save power?

Tags: power, code-optimization, code-review

Along all the "advanced" methods [described in this article](http://www.gammon.com.au/power), does simple method as downscaling processor while `delay` makes a difference on power consumption? How much time does the clock alternation takes itself?

Is below example valid?

```
#include <avr/power.h>

void setup() {}

void loop {

    /* 
       here some jobs to do...
    */

    clock_prescale_set(clock_div_256); // downscale clock
    delay(200); // wait
    clock_prescale_set(clock_div_1); // restore clock
}
```

Comment: i don't think that will accomplish anything; it's not like there are background threads...

Comment: It's not running background threads, no, but the delay function doesn't just 'pause'. It runs a loop waiting for the time to pass. If you scale down the clock the cpu will process slower and use less power. I'm not super familiar with the clock prescaler, so perhaps someone could verify, but a delay(200) with a div 265 prescale would actually take just over 51 seconds, i think. ?

Comment: @Mazaryk: if that's the case, power-saving mode would be better right? I just don't see shaving empty cycles as a big savings, but i could be wrong; most of my experience is with ESP8266s...

Comment: @dandavis: I'm not sure, but I would think sleeping would yield better power savings but that's just a guess. Best way to know for sure would be to test and measure it.

Comment: @dandavis setting the clock divider is major power-saver, see the article i linked (esp. reply #7 http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11497&reply=7#reply7)

Comment: @madneon: interesting. i think sleeping still shaves more, but that's nice and simple whilst still pretty good for not screwing around with watchdogs and brownouts or suspending IOs like spi and serial. With the right setup, you can get a 3.3v one all the way down to ~5µA. but not as easily for sure. thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducing the CPU frequency should work, but I would expect better
savings by sleeping during the busy loop:

```c++
#include <avr/sleep.h>

void sleepy_delay(uint32_t duration)
{
    uint32_t start = millis();
    while (millis() - start < duration) {
        sleep_mode();
    }
}
```

Note that the sleep will be interrupted at least on every Timer 0
overflow interrupt, which happens every 1024 µs (that's what
increments the value returned by `millis()`), so there is no risk of
oversleeping. You could add some `power_*_disable()` calls for better
savings.

Comment: 1024 µs "wakeup" thats 1 ms, so your loop will execute every milisecond assuming that it takes less then 1 ms to execute `millis()` with 2 operations (substract, compare+jump), right? So does this method actually saves power, aka is Arduino that fast? ;)

Comment: @madneon: `millis()` is fast, and subtract+compare+jump is only a few CPU cycles. With this loop the Arduino will be awake only a tiny fraction of the time, mostly executing the Timer 0 overflow ISR.